# Generar un número positivo o negativo según condición usando Faker

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo el siguente `factory` en un proyecto en laravel

```
use App\Model\Logistica\Movement;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Movement::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'quantity' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 30),
        'description' => $faker->text(20),
        'log_article_id' => function () {
            return \App\Model\Logistica\Article::query()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'log_sub_deposit_id' => function () {
            return \App\Model\Logistica\SubDeposit::query()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'log_user_id' => function () {
            return \App\User::query()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'log_provision_id' => function () {
            return \App\Model\Logistica\Provision::query()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
        'log_movement_type_id' => function () {
            return \App\Model\Logistica\MovementType::query()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

En la columna `quantity` estoy generando números entre el 1 y el 30:

`'quantity' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 30),`

Quiero saber si puedo generar valores según una condición, por ejemplo, si en `log_movement_type_id` se generó el valor `1`, entonces que inserte un número negativo en `quantity`

En la tabla `log_movement_types`, que corresponde al Modelo `\App\Model\Logistica\MovementType`, ahi dentro tengo nada mas que 5 registros, con ID del 1 al 5 respectivamente.

Lo que quiero es sencillo: si en el siguente código genera un `1` o `4`, que el valor de `quantity` sea negativo.

```
'log_movement_type_id' => function () {
            return \App\Model\Logistica\MovementType::query()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma es que generes el valor que vas a usar de condición antes de hacer el `return`. Por ejemplo:

```
$factory->define(Movement::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $log_movement_type_id = \App\Model\Logistica\MovementType::query()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
    $quantity = $log_movement_type_id == 1 || $log_movement_type_id == 4? $faker->numberBetween(-30, -1): $faker->numberBetween(1, 30);

    return [
        'quantity' => $quantity,
        // tus otros campos ...
        'log_movement_type_id' => $log_movement_type_id,
    ];
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Era mucho mas facil de lo que pensaba. Tengo que seguir practicando.